# What type of mySQL data should I pick for a list of friends?

Tags: php, mysql

i'm making a website and i need to add a list of friends

should i take like a TEXT variable that would contain ids of users and i would be using separators like | ??
would it work or is it a better way ?

Comment: No. See normalisation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should make a separate table with a foreign key for the user that owns the friend list and a foreign key for the user in the list. This makes managing the friends list much easier since you won't have to edit and parse a string to remove friends from the list.

As @Strawberry mentioned, this kind of data design is called [normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)